# Zariski vs etale torsors over abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, etale-cohomology, etale-covers, torsors

> **Question.** Let $A$ be an abelian variety (say, over the complex numbers), $G$ an algebraic group, $c$ a class in $H^1_{\rm et}(A, G)$. Denote the multiplication by $N$ map on A by $m_N:A\to A$. Does there exist an $N$ such that $m_N^*(c)$ is in the image of $$ H^1_{\rm Zar}(A, G) \longrightarrow H^1_{\rm et}(A, G)? $$

Concretely, I am asking whether every etale $G$-torsor over $A$ becomes
Zariski-locally trivial after a finite etale cover. This question
makes sense for an arbitrary scheme $X$, not necessarily an abelian
variety, but we should probably assume that $X$ is a $K(\pi, 1)$, or at
least that the (Artin--Mazur) $\pi_2(X)$ vanishes (see 3) below).

Special cases I am able to do:

1. $G$ finite: then ok since $c$ corresponds to a representation of the
   fundamental group,
2. $G$ a special group in the sense of Grothendieck (e.g. $G=\mathbb{G}_m$, $\mathbb{G}_a$,
   $GL_n$, $Sp_{2n}$): then ok with $N=1$,
3. $G = PGL_n$, then the obstruction to lifting a $PGL_n$-torsor to an
   $SL_n$-torsor is a class in $H^2(A, \mu_n)$. Now we use the fact that $A$ is a $K(\pi, 1)$ to show that we can kill this class by a finite etale cover.
4. $G$ is an abelian variety - I haven't thought this through carefully,
   but I guess this is also ok by Poincare reducibility.

The arguments above more generally show that (a) if we have a short exact sequence
$$ 1\to H\to G'\to G \to 1 $$
with $H$ finite and $G'$ special, then the statement holds for $G$, (b) if we have a short exact sequence
$$ 1\to G_0\to G \to G_1 \to 1 $$
with $G_1$ finite, then $G$ satisfies the required property if $G_0$ does. It is unclear however whether given a short exact sequence
$$ 1\to G'\to G\to G''\to 1 $$
with $G'$ and $G''$ satisfying the required property we can deduce that $G$ does as well (but $G$ is special if $G'$ and $G''$ are).

Comment: $H^1_{\mathrm{Zar}}(A,G)$ is trivial when $G$ is finite.

Comment: @abx yes, and this is how we get (b)

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread the question.